# Updating specific firebase field using recyclerview button in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I'm developing a voting app using Android Studio in Java that uses `RecyclerView` to list all candidates from the Firebase database. I'm able to list all candidates, but can't implement the vote button to only update a specific candidate's total votes.

[image: Database structure]

The data is picked and displayed in a `RecyclerView` as follows:
Candidates information in `RecyclerView`:
[image: Candidates information in RecyclerView.]

I need each time a user clicks on the vote button, the database `totalVotes` field is updated with a +1.

MyAdapter code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList <Candidate> candidates;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


    public MyAdapter (Context c, ArrayList<Candidate> p){
        context = c;
        candidates =p;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false));
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(candidates.get(position).getFirstname());
        holder.party.setText(candidates.get(position).getParty());
        holder.category.setText(candidates.get(position).getCategory());
        Picasso.get().load(candidates.get(position).getImageurl()).into(holder.profilepic);

        holder.onClick(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return candidates.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView name, party, category;
        ImageView profilepic;
        Button vote;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            party = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.party);
            profilepic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
            category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            vote = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vote);
        }

        public void onClick(int position){
            vote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```

AllCandidates class that handles the adapter:

```
private DatabaseReference reference;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Candidate> list;
    private ArrayList<CandidateIMage> listimage;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private DatabaseReference imagereference;
    FirebaseStorage storage;
    StorageReference storageReference;

    private static final String TAG = "AllCandidates";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_candidates);

        //reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("candidates");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        list = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
        listimage = new ArrayList<CandidateIMage>();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        Query presidentquery = reference.child("candidates").orderByChild("category").equalTo("President");
        presidentquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Candidate p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Candidate.class);
                        //String userId = dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                        //System.out.println("User id to be passed is: "+userId);
                        list.add(p);
                    }
                    adapter = new MyAdapter(AllCandidates.this, list);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        };
    }
```

I had tried to add this code to the vote.onclicklostener but it is not working:

```html
public void onClick(final int position){
            postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("candidates");
            vote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                        @Override
                        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                            Candidate p = mutableData.getValue(Candidate.class);
                            if (p == null) {
                                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                            } else {
                                int fetched = p.getTotalVotes();
                                fetched = fetched + 1;

                                String userId = postRef.push().getKey();
                                // Set value and report transaction success
                                postRef.child(userId).child("totalVotes").setValue(fetched);

                                //mutableData.setValue(p);
                                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // Transaction completed
                            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
                        }
                    });
                }


            });
        }
```

My Candidate m0del looks like this:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Candidate {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String party;
    private String category;
    private String candidateemail;
    private String imageurl;
    public Integer totalVotes;

    // Default constructor required for calls to
    // DataSnapshot.getValue(Candidate.class)
    public Candidate() {
    }

    public Candidate(String imageurl, String candidateemail, String firstname, String lastname, String party, String category, Integer totalVotes) {

        this.candidateemail = candidateemail;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.party = party;
        this.category = category;
        this.totalVotes = totalVotes;
    }

    public String getCandidateemail() {
        return candidateemail;
    }

    public void setCandidateemail(String candidateemail) {
        this.candidateemail = candidateemail;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getParty() {
        return party;
    }

    public void setParty(String party) {
        this.party = party;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public Integer getTotalVotes() {
        return totalVotes;
    }

    public void setTotalVotes(Integer totalVotes) {
        this.totalVotes = totalVotes;
    }

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: When I click on the vote button, it creates a new record in the database, instead of updating the totaLVotes field of the specific voted for candidate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment:

> When I click on the vote button, it creates a new record in the database, instead of updating the `totaLVotes` field of the specific voted for a candidate.

This is happening because you are using the transaction in the wrong way. When you are using the following lines of code:

```
String userId = postRef.push().getKey();
postRef.child(userId).child("totalVotes").setValue(fetched);
```

You are pushing in the database every time a new total since the call to the `.push()` generates a new random key each time is called. To update only the `totalVotes` property, please use the following method:

```
public static void updateTotalVotes(String operation) {
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference totalVotesRef = rootRef.child("candidates").child("-M35sglMi8onCgvEDzbm").child("totalVotes");
    totalVotesRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Integer votes = mutableData.getValue(Integer.class);
            if (votes == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (operation.equals("increaseTotalVotes")) {
                mutableData.setValue(votes + 1);
            } else if (operation.equals("decreaseTotalVotes")){
                mutableData.setValue(votes - 1);
            }

            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    });
}
```

See, you have to set use a reference that points to the `totalVotes` property. Now kick it off with:

```
updateTotalVotes("increaseTotalVotes");
```

For more information please check the official documentation regarding [saving data as transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Comment: Thank @Alex. Let me try this. Also, in this line: DatabaseReference totalVotesRef = rootRef.child("candidates").child("-M35sglMi8onCgvEDzbm").child("totalVotes"); if I wanted to get the candidate key from the database instead of hard coding it (-M35sglMi8onCgvEDzbm) into the rootRef, would that be possible?

Comment: In that case, you should save that id into a variable and use it for future operations. Usually, we are using as a unique identifier the `uid` of the user that comes from the [Firebase authentication process](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and **not** that pushed id. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: thank a lot for the first answer, it worked, and now the totalVote is being updated for the specific candidate key. However, I still cant fetch the key from the database and store it in a variable as you had suggested in the second comment. Any help?

Comment: Good to hear that it worked :) Regarding the second issue, without seeing what you have tried, I cannot be much of a help. So please post another question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: if you can look at the MyAdapter.java activity, I have an onBindViewHolder method, which sort of renders each individual read from the database and places it in the recyclerview. I need that each time it renders the candidates information, it should also get the candidate key and store it in a variable

Comment: This question is out of the scope of the initial question. That's why I recommended you to post a new question, so we can take a look at it.